# Feature selection using Fselector Library

Tags: r

I have a data frame contains terms (in column) and number of terms in each cell. I want to select the most important terms (features) from train2 data frame.I am using Fselector library as below :

```
library(dplyr)
library(party)
library(FSelector)
importance <- importance(train2)
varImportance <- data.frame(Variables = row.names(importance),
Importance=   round(importance[,'MeanDecreaseGini'],2))
#Create a rank variable based on importance
rankImportance <- varImportance %>% mutate(
Rank = paste0('#',dense_rank(desc(Importance))))
ggplot(rankImportance,aes(x = reorder(Variables, Importance),
y = Importance, fill = Importance)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity') +
geom_text(aes(x = Variables, y = 0.5,label = Rank),
hjust=0, vjust=0.55,size = 4, colour = 'red') +
labs(x = 'Variables')+
coord_flip()
```

I got this error:
      Error in UseMethod("importance") : 
      no applicable method for 'importance'applied to an
      object of class"c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Comment: `randomForest::importance` argument is an object of class `randomForest`, not a `data.frame`

Comment: I'd recommend using more precise variable names and avoiding mixing cases (`importance` and `Importance` are 2 different objects, but mistaking one for the other is very easy)

Comment: @HubertL How can I select important features for SVM, liniear regression model?